# Trying to display Emoji in a UILabel using StringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unicode, emoji

Im trying to fetch a random Emoji character from an array. how can i convert these values into unicode format without XCode having a fit? :

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\U%@",[emojis randomObject]];
```

I get : `\U used with no following hex digits` every time.

can you not construct a unicode format like that?

Comment: What is `emojis` variable?

Comment: yeah emojis is an array of strings (hex values)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here was my solution:

```
NSString *code = emojArray[i];
NSScanner *hexScan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:code];
unsigned int hexNum;
[hexScan scanHexInt:&hexNum];
UTF32Char inputChar = hexNum;
NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&inputChar length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
```

`res`, when displayed in a UILabel is now an emoji.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!!